# Flex: Group items in DataGrid

Tags: apache-flex, datagrid, advanceddatagrid

I have a DataGrid with info like this:

```
Associate   Amount  Time    Customer

John Doe    2   9am Sam Smith
John Doe    2   10am    Berry Cooper
Bill Ace    1   9am Sandy James
```

Repeating the name and amount gets redundant so I would like it to look something like this:

```
Associate   Amount  

John Doe    2       
Bill Ace    1
```

Then when you select one, it expands to show the times and customers for the selected associate. I hope this makes sense...I am currently just using a DataGrid but I can use an AdvancedDataGrid if thats needed...I am pretty sure something like this can be done, I just don't know how.

My data is in xml and looks like this:

```
<stat associate="John Doe" date="08/12/09" amount="2" time="9 am" customer="Sam Smith"/>
<stat associate="John Doe" date="08/12/09" amount="2" time="10 am" customer="Berry Cooper"/>
<stat associate="Bill Ace" date="08/12/09" amount="1" time="9 am" customer="Sandy James"/>
```

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll want to use an AdvancedDataGrid with a GroupingCollection. See [here](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=advdatagrid_08.html)